# ggdendrogram for a large number of nodes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, ggdendro

I'm trying to plot a `dendrogram` with a large number of nodes using `ggdendrogram` and it's pretty slow (compared to `dendextend` for example):

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))


require(ggdendro)
require(dendextend)
require(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(ggdendrogram(dend,rotate=T,labels=F,size=4,theme_dendro=F))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                   expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 ggdendrogram(dend, rotate = T, labels = F, size = 4, theme_dendro = F) 394.3181 409.3591 431.0981 412.515 416.4568 1346.844   100

> microbenchmark(dend %>% plot(horiz = TRUE))
Unit: milliseconds
                        expr      min     lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dend %>% plot(horiz = TRUE) 138.7253 207.92 214.5278 208.8807 211.2602 640.0316   100
```

Is there any way to speed it up to make it comparable with `dendextend`'s plot's speed?

Also, whether I specify `rotate=T` or

```
ggdendrogram(dend,rotate=F,labels=F,size=4,theme_dendro=F)+coord_flip()
```

I get the dendrogram pointing left:
[image]

but I want it to point right instead. Any idea how to get that to work?

Comment: This should work: `ggdendrogram(dend,rotate=F,labels=F,size=4,theme_dendro=F) + coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, the dendextend package replaces ggdendro.

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))
require(dendextend)
gg_dend <- as.ggdend(dend)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(gg_dend, labels = F)+coord_flip()+ scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: I see. But that's even slower: > microbenchmark(as.ggdend(dend))
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 as.ggdend(dend) 553.2726 558.605 564.0724 561.7158 566.2058 600.0285   100

Comment: The as.ggdend should be slow since it extract more features (colors, line width, etc.). But once you have used as.ggdend the object can be plotted in the normal ggplot way. I don't see a simple way for making as.ggdend faster.